# what is best way to combine multi graphs in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

[image: Multi Graph]
i have multiple trained graphs in tensorflow, and i would like to combine them together for post-processing, as shown in figure.

After googling a while, i am able to find a common way to do that, [LINK](https://bretahajek.com/2017/04/importing-multiple-tensorflow-models-graphs/). However, by doing this, i might need to run the graphs linearly (one after one). my question is, is this the only way to "ensemble" multiple trained graphs?

**EDIT 1:**
graph code which is not including the training step:

```py
layer_def={
        "l1": 21,
        "l2": 42,
        "l3": 42,
        "l4": 84 ,
        "l5": 84,
        "l6": 168,
        "l7": 84,
        "l8": 42,
        "l9": 21,
        "l10": 16
        }

graph = tf.Graph()

input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 128], name="Feature_Input")
with graph.as_default(): 
    with tf.name_scope("SampleOp"):
        input_layer = dense_layer_with_BN_l2(input, units=30)# it is a function warp of linear layer with batch-normalization and returns L2-norm
        for key, value in layer_def.items():
            input_layer = dense_layer_with_BN_l2(input_layer, value, name=key)
        K_gain = probability_sample(input_layer, 16) # it is a function warp of tfp.distributions.MultivariateNormalDiag.sample

sess = tf.Session(graph=graph)
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
saver = tf.train.Saver()
sess.run(K_gain ,feed_dict={input : 0})
save_path = saver.save(sess, "./model/SampleOp.ckpt")
```

and which the **Graph1**, **Graph2** and **Graph3** are all trained with different datasets to expect have different weights.

What i am currently doing is:

```py
Graph1 = ImportGraph("./model/SampleOp1.ckpt")
Graph2 = ImportGraph("./model/SampleOp2.ckpt")
Graph3 = ImportGraph("./model/SampleOp3.ckpt")

Output1 = Graph1.run(FeedDict)
Output2 = Graph2.run(FeedDict)
Output3 = Graph3.run(FeedDict)

result = post_Processing([Output1, Output2, Output3])
```

i want to know if there is any other efficient way to "manipulate" ("combine", "ensemble" or any other) the tensorflow graph to achieve my purpose.

Comment: Can you give us a simplified version of the code you used to generate these graphs, and what you tried to get them to run together? Without some code for context, we're kinda flying blind.

Comment: @JordanSinger Thank you for your comment, and i added some description code. Hope that make it a little bit clear.